# Как сохранить НЕ дефолтные данные в Settings.settings

Tags: c#

Как сохранить не дефолтные данные в файле Settings.settings?.Пробовал так

```
      private void SettingsSavingEventHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
        // Добавьте здесь код для обработки события SettingsSaving.
        marker = WpfApplication16.MainWindow.getMarker();
        delay = WpfApplication16.MainWindow.getDelay();
        senderEmail = WpfApplication16.MainWindow.getCredentials()[0];
        recipientEmail = WpfApplication16.MainWindow.getCredentials()[1];
        subject = WpfApplication16.MainWindow.getCredentials()[2];
        text = WpfApplication16.MainWindow.getCredentials()[3];
        password = WpfApplication16.MainWindow.getCredentials()[4];
    }
```

,но при последующих запусках значения остаются дефолтными.При вызове `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` значения все равно затираются при перезапуске приложения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получите доступ к параметру и присвойте ему новое значение:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.AliceBlue;
```

Если необходимо сохранять изменения параметров между сеансами приложения, вызовите метод Save, как показано ниже.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Официальное руководство [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx)